# Python - Never Ending Multiple While Loops Interferring with Other Definitions

Tags: python, dictionary, while-loop

I'm currently making a scoring system where a user can join the event as a team or by themselves and in order to do this I was using while loops as a form of simple validation. I used while loop to prevent user entering the event without their name. The problem I am having is that I have different definitions if they want to join the event as a team or by themselves and the while loops inside this defintions keeps interferring with each other and by interfering I mean that even after I asked the user for their name the other defintion comes up and asks for the user for their name again

```
def team_menu():

 global teamS

 team_player = ""

 while team_player:
   team_player = input("What is your name:")
   print("""\n Available Teams \n
   1) Team Ahab
   2) Team Ishmael

  \n3) Go back to Main Menu\n""")

 team_choice = ""
 team_choice_option = ["1","2","3"] # all valid choices on team menu

 while team_choice not in team_choice_option:
 team_choice = input("Enter your choice here:")

 teamS["Crew "+team_choice]["Team "+team_choice]
 print(teamS["Crew "+team_choice])
 print("Thank you for Joining Team "+ team_choice)
```

Here's my second def that keeps interfering its while loops with the first one

```
def individual():
 global solo_player

 solo_name=""    
 while solo_name == "":
   solo_name = input("What is your name:")
   print(""" \nIndividual Menu and Available Spots\n
      1) Player 1
      2) Player 2""")

  solo_menu_options = ["1","2"]

  while solo_menu not in solo_menu_options:
  solo_menu = input("Please enter your choice here:")    

  solo_player["Contestant "+solo_menu]["Player "+solo_menu].append(solo_name)

  print(solo_player["Contestant "+solo_menu])

  print("Thank you for taking the spot of Player "+solo_menu)
```

My ideal output would be that the definition would just stop as soon I entered all the necessary user inputs

Comment: Can you clarify " I used while loop to prevent the users from going furthur down my program and so I can store their names into my dictionary." and "after entering user input the other definition comes up with its own while loops. Here's what I've done"? I'm finding this quite confusing.

Comment: Ok I'll try and do that

Comment: I think you mean `while not team_player:` if you want to prevent them from entering an empty string. `while team_player:` will loop while the name is non-empty. That loop should never had been entered in the first place though, so something's off about the example here.

Comment: what do you by non empty? Sorry I'm new to python so Idk

Comment: And also, you have `input("What is your name:")` is two different places in your code. For the record, loops in different parts of a program can't "interfere with each other" unless you have multiple threads going at once, or are abusing globals.

Comment: oh ok I understand